# json to lua with multiple stings backslash and dot

Tags: json, lua, backslash

Hello i'm trying to use Json from my washer with lua. It's for visualizing the samsung in Domoitcz.

A part of the Json what i get from https://api.smartthings.com/v1/devices/abcd-1234-abcd is:

```
"main": {
"washerJobState": {
            "value": "wash"
},
"mnhw": {
            "value": "1.0"
},
"data": {
          "value": "{
                \"payload\":{
                 \"x.com.samsung.da.state\":\"Run\",\"x.com.samsung.da.delayEndTime\":\"00:00:00\",\"x.com.samsung.da.remainingTime\":\"01:34:00\",\"if\":[\"oic.if.baseline\",\"oic.if.a\"],\"x.com.samsung.da.progressPercentage\":\"2\",\"x.com.samsung.da.supportedProgress\":[\"None\",\"Wash\",\"Rinse\",\"Spin\",\"Finish\"],\"x.com.samsung.da.progress\":\"Wash\",\"rt\":[\"x.com.samsung.da.operation\"]}}"
        },
"washerRinseCycles": {
            "value": "3"
        },
        "switch": {
            "value": "on"
        },
```

if i use in my script

```
local switch = item.json.main.switch.value
```

I got the valua on or off and i can use it for showing the status of the washer.

i'm trying to find out how to get the "data"value in my script, there are more items with dots en backslhases:

```
local remainingTime = rt.data.value.payload['x.com.samsung.da.remainingTime']
```

or

```
local remainingTime = rt.data.value['\payload']['\x.com.samsung.da.remainingTime']
```

i tried some more opions with 'or // , "" but always got a nill value.

Can someone explain me how to get:

\"x.com.samsung.da.remainingTime\":\"01:34:00\"
\"x.com.samsung.da.progressPercentage\":\"2\",

All the " , \, x.,  ar confusing me

Below is my script to test where i only left the Json log  (Dzvents Lua Based) i get an error:

dzVents/generated_scripts/Samsung_v3.lua:53: attempt to index a nil value (global 'json') i don't heave any idea how te use/adjust my code for decode the string.

```
local json = require"json"  -- the JSON library
local outer = json.decode(your_JSON_string)
local rt = outer.main
local inner = json.decode(rt.data.value)
local remainingTime = inner.payload['x.com.samsung.da.remainingTime']
```

```
local API = 'API'
local Device = 'Device'


local LOGGING = true

--Define dz Switches
local WM_STATUS =  'WM Status'  --Domoitcz virtual switch ON/Off state  Washer


return 
{
    on = 
    {
        timer = 
        {
            'every 1 minutes', -- just an example to trigger the request
        },

        httpResponses = 
        {
            'trigger', -- must match with the callback passed to the openURL command
        },
    },

    logging = 
    { 
        level = domoticz.LOG_DEBUG ,
    }, 

    execute = function(dz, item)

        local wm_status = dz.devices(WM_STATUS)

        if item.isTimer then
            dz.openURL({
                url = 'https://api.smartthings.com/v1/devices/'.. Device .. '/states',
                headers = { ['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '.. API },
                method = 'GET',
                callback = 'trigger', -- see httpResponses above.

            })
        end

        if (item.isHTTPResponse) then
            if item.ok then
                if (item.isJSON) then


                   rt = item.json.main
            --      outer = json.decode'{"payload":{"x.com.samsung.da.state":"Run","x.com.samsung.da.delayEndTime":"00:00:00","x.com.samsung.da.remainingTime":"00:40:00","if":["oic.if.baseline","oic.if.a"],"x.com.samsung.da.progressPercentage":"81","x.com.samsung.da.supportedProgress":["None","Weightsensing","Wash","Rinse","Spin","Finish"],"x.com.samsung.da.progress":"Rinse","rt":["x.com.samsung.da.operation"]}}
                inner = json.decode(rt.data.value)
            --        local remainingTime = inner.payload['x.com.samsung.da.remainingTime']


                        dz.utils.dumpTable(rt) -- this will show how the table is structured
            --          dz.utils.dumpTable(inner)

                        local washerSpinLevel = rt.washerSpinLevel.value
            --       local remainingTime = inner.payload['x.com.samsung.da.remainingTime']




                        dz.log('Debuggg washerSpinLevel:' ..  washerSpinLevel, dz.LOG_DEBUG)
                     dz.log('Debuggg remainingTime:' ..  remainingTime, dz.LOG_DEBUG)

            --          dz.log('Resterende tijd:' .. remainingTime, dz.LOG_INFO)
            --          dz.log(dz.utils.fromJSON(item.data))


                  --  end
                elseif LOGGING == true then
                    dz.log('There was a problem handling the request', dz.LOG_ERROR)
                    dz.log(item, dz.LOG_ERROR)
                end
            end
        end
end
}
```

Comment: Where is API reference available?  I'm talking about functions in `dz.utils`.  Probably there should be a JSON decoding function.

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird construction: a serialized JSON inside a normal JSON.
This means you have to invoke deserialization twice:

```
local json = require"json"  -- the JSON library
local outer = json.decode(your_JSON_string)
local rt = outer.main
local inner = json.decode(rt.data.value)
local remainingTime = inner.payload['x.com.samsung.da.remainingTime']
```